# Processbuilder to execute jar files with arguement

Tags: java

I would like to execute a jar file with some arguements using ProcessBuilder, but I am not sure how to construct the syntax.

For example, I wanted to execute the following :

```
processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", "java" ,"-jar" + this.jar_filepath + " " + this.tc_name + " " + this.test_data + " " + this.test_result);
```

Basically, I am trying to execute a jar file located at `jar_filepath` and sending the content of the arguments `tc_name, test_data` and `test_result` to the main method of the executed jar files.

This is obviously wrong, which I hope to have guidance on how to properly construct the syntax.

**UPDATE:**
For KevinBoone:

```
 try {
      Process process = processBuilder.start();
      process.waitFor()  ;
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
                              InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
      }

      int exitCode = process.waitFor();
      System.out.println("\nExited with error code : " + exitCode);
}
catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
} 
catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you capturing `stdout` and `stderr` from the `cmd.exe` process? This will probably tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @KevinBoone I have updated my question with code the comes after the processBUilder. Is this the ````stdout```` and ````stderr````  that you are referring to ?

Comment: Also, would be great if you can advice me on how to properly construct the right syntax to execute my requirement. Thanks

Comment: They are *all* separate arguments, so don't use string concatenation: `processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", "java", "-jar", this.jar_filepath, this.tc_name, this.test_data, this.test_result);`

Comment: @Andreas, that works. But I encounter another issue. I'll create another question for that. But thanks for the your solution.

Comment: @testerABC -- sorry if this is off-topic, but reading the process's `stdout` after calling `waitFor()` isn't very robust. Whether it works or not depends on the intricacies of the buffering provided by the platform. But that's not your immediate problem, I think.

Comment: @KevinBoone No worries, thanks for the sharing. At least it's something I can take note of moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that other parts are fine,

> ```
> "-jar" + this.jar_filepath
> ```

is missing a space, it should be

```
"-jar " + this.jar_filepath
     ^
```

Or just use `,` everywhere and let ProcessBuilder to insert the spaces.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but still it doesn't run. I have a waitFor(), and the value is 1.

Comment: I have use                                                                                                                 
````final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start java -jar " + start.jar_filepath + " " + start.tc_name + " " + start.test_data + " " + start.test_result + " " + start.test_cycle);```` which principally works, but I would like to 'migrate' that to Processbuilder

Comment: @testerABC just to make sure: do you actually `start()` the command? Because `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` runs the command on spot, but `ProcessBuilder.command()` just prepares. You may want to add these details to the question itself, by the way.

Comment: Yeap, I did. As a matter of fact, I have just added the subsequent codes after the Processbuilder. Feel free to refer to it. Thanks